# Difference between members & properties?

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a qooxdoo class , which parent class is `qx.core.Object` .

```
qx.Class.define("qx.model.MyClass",
{
  extend : qx.core.Object,
  construct : function() {

  },
  statics : {

  },
  members : {
    apple : null
  },
  properties : {
    apple : { init : "Apple" }
  }
});
```

What is the difference of variable in *members* and *properties* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The members section defines fields that will be available as plain JavaScript properties on instances of MyClass. qooxdoo's properties offer a number of features on top, including automatically generated accessor and mutator methods, validation, and change events.

This page explains the differences:
http://manual.qooxdoo.org/2.1.x/pages/core/understanding_properties.html

And here's the article on qooxdoo properties:
http://manual.qooxdoo.org/2.1.x/pages/core/defining_properties.html